# Change default index.php when using admin route

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, autoload

I'm currently on a project which gave me a small headache after trying to find a solution for a tiny problem I've bumped onto.

At the moment, my application loads my index.php file on every single page request it gets. Inside my index, the application fires-up some basic stuff, sets some variables etc.
Well, the thing I'm currently looking for is that I would like to let my server load a different file (for example admin.php) as default. But, this only needs to happen when the url sub-directory is set as http://www.mydomain.com/admin/

So the server needs to handle every little thing exactly the same, but when the route is set as /admin/, its needs to autoload the admin.php instead of the default index.php.

Currently my .htaccess file looks like this

```
# mod-rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

**EDIT:** To clear things up and visualize it a bit more:

- http://www.mydomain.com/users/me/logs/ -> index.php
- http://www.mydomain.com/admin/users/me/logs/ -> admin.php
- http://www.mydomain.com/admin/stackoverflow/questions -> admin.php - http://www.mydomain.com/stackoverflow/questions -> index.php

Inside these two file I load a new Zend_Application (ZF1)

Comment: You could copy this .htaccess file and put it in the /admin folder with the new rule changing index.php to admin.php

Comment: Sorry for me not being clear enough. The index.php and admin.php file are both in the root directory. The application need to switch between the two if /admin/ or not. Hope this makes it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin.php [L]
```

Your .htaccess would look likes:

```
# mod-rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

**Update 1**

and if you try the RewriteRules in the following order:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*(admin).*$ admin.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Such a simple addition to my current code, but solved the problem! First entry didn't work, but with the update it works like a charm :D

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On

# handle requests to /admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ admin.php [NC,L]

# handle all other requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but for some reason it skips you addition and just autoload the index.php. I've tested it by turning index.php and admin.php around with a helloworld echo. It's shows me the helloworld on every page /some/things and loads the index.php only without any additional routes.

Answer (score 0):

To un-complicate things, you could have used a common boostrap script which would conditionally include the files. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ bootstrap.php [NC,L]
```

Then, in bootstrap.php

```
<?php

if(USER_IS_ADMIN){
  require('admin.php');
}else{
  require('index.php');
}
```

If you really need to check via htaccess, you might like to see [this SOF thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747442/redirect-to-specific-page-if-not-logged-in-htaccess)

Comment: Simple and real straightforward solution, but would like to handle it within my .htaccess. I'm not totally sure on which part you're referring in the SOF thread. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: My bad, it looks like that answer wouldn't help too much in this case. Just had a through read :)

Comment: I was trying to make something out of the thread but could figure out what you ment haha. No problem, maybe also my explanation skills arent the best in the world :p

Comment: @Wimbjorno I did some search on this. Interesting approach I must say. How about using cookie ? You could add a rewrite condition like for example :  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*user_id=(\d+).*$ [NC]

Comment: I've cleared up my question a bit more. I appreciate you help but I'm not sure if you understand my question. Could you please read everthing after EDIT. Hope it make a bit more sense :D