# htaccess redirect / login on subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i got a question about `htaccess`.

I got an page: `www.example.com`.

When a visitor comes on `www.example.com`, he should be redirected to `www.google.de`

If i got to use `www.example.com/admin`, i want to have a `htaccess` login.

When I am logged in and I go to `www.example.com` 
i wanna see my normal page, and don't have the redirect to `www.google.de`.

I googled a lot but didn't find the answer for this problem.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Similar topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747442/redirect-to-specific-page-if-not-logged-in-htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect to specific page if not logged in - .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747442/redirect-to-specific-page-if-not-logged-in-htaccess)